# how to use an API on web, using Ajax and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post, onreadystatechange

I want to implement a login by calling an API using Ajax and Javascript.

User enters username and password and by clicking a button "login()" would be called. If input is correct it should open the welcome page. I implemented it as below. But it does not work!

```
function login() {
  var url = "http://...";
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  console.log("before function. ")    
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("before if. ")
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("inside if. " + xhr.responseText);
      window.open(welcome);
    }
  };

  var obj = { UserName: username , Password: password }
  var data = JSON.stringify(obj);

  xhr.send(data);
  console.log("END ");
}
```

As suggested, I added several console log to debug it and I found out that it never run inside the if. There is no error on console and here's the output on console:

```
before function. 
END
before if.
```

(before was repeated 3 times)

I have already checked API by Postman. It works.
If username and password are correct, it returns all information of user and the http status code is 201. If input is incorrect then it returns an error message and status code is 401.

Comment: Is this a cross domain request? Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: *"I added several alerts to debug it and I found out that it never run: alert(xhr.responseText)"* - Then what *did* it do?  Don't just toss in `alert()` statements to debug, use the browser's debugging tools.  Was there an error in the development console?  Did the code execute in the script debugger?  Was the AJAX request made?  What was the server's response?

Comment: yes it is. And no error on console.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I modified my code to use console.log instead of alert:

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("before if. ")
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("inside if. " + xhr.responseText);
      window.open("welcome.html");
    }
};
  
the only output on console is "before if. "

Comment: @Amy2020: So you've established that the code is successfully running.  The `if` condition is simply `false`.  That's what an `if` block does, it *conditionally* executes only *if* the condition is true.  Time to start debugging to examine the runtime state of your objects.  Is `this` a reference to `xhr` when that function runs?  What values are in `readyState` and `status`?  What about `statusText` and `responseText`?  Any other relevant values?  In the network tab in your browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the response?  You need to debug.

Comment: @David Thank you so much! solved! this.readyState was changing from 2 to 3 and to 4. But this.status was always 201! which I incorrectly had compared it with 200 in if statement.